# shape with drawable resource inside programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

Currently I have a action bar menu with few items inside.

I am trying to have a menu item with shape which has a drawable

The code i get so far:

```
ShapeDrawable circle = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        circle.getPaint().setColor(Color.GREEN);
        circle.setIntrinsicHeight(120);
        circle.setIntrinsicWidth(120);

        circle.setBounds(0, 0, 120, 120);

        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_1).setIcon(circle);
```

However currently only looks like a green circle, I want inside to have a drawable icon.

for [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWDj9.png)

Comment: Can show an example with image so we can see what your idea exactly looks?

Comment: I have added - https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWDj9.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just create `icon.xml` in `drawable` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid
                android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

            <size
                android:width="70dp"
                android:height="70dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map"  android:gravity="center">
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and use it like this:

```
 menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_1).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.icon));
```

[image]